# Assumptions on one-way functions

Tags: hash, one-way-function

What are the assumptions we make to propose a one-way function? I only know of some number theoretic assumptions, but what are the other assumptions you can possibly make, which if true, would imply that $f$ is a one-way function?

(Considering pre-image resistant hash functions, what is the assumption there? Hashes as far as I know do not rely on any assumption other than the fact that it *seems* to  be hard)

**Edit**:

Example: Say we assume factoring a semiprime $N = pq$ is hard. Then we can say that the function $f(p,q) = p*q$ is one-way. What other assumptions exist?

Comment: Factoring large semiprimes only _seems_ to be hard too.

Comment: @SqueamishOssifrage Yes, but that assumption is necessary and sufficient to prove that a one-way function exists. (I'm not sure if there exists such a concrete assumption for hashes)

Comment: The example in your edit is backwards. $f(p,q) = p*q$ is one-way, not $f(N) = (p,q)$

Answer (score 2):

#### General

The existence of a *"perfect"* one-way function is not proven. Such a function would prove that [P $\ne$ NP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P_versus_NP_problem), which is still an unsolved problem in mathematics / computer science.

One-way functions are per definition hard to invert, but easy to check. One example, that are assumed that they are one-way, are hash-functions:

You can easily create a hash of a given input, but you can't get the input from a given hash in a *reasonable* amount of time, assuming the input is long enough.

Some properties of a one-way function:

- Easy to compute, but *infeasible* to compute the inverse of the function in the average case
- [Preimage resistant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preimage_attack)

#### Hashes

We assume that there exists a perfect one-way hash function: Hash functions are a special kind of one-way functions, since they reduce a possible large input to a fixed length smaller hash value, the term is a *[one-way compression function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-way_compression_function)*. This means that there is a data-loss and also means that mulitple different inputs can have the same hash value ([pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle)). Data-loss here means, that it's impossible to retrieve the unknown original input from a given hash-value.

Comment: No. Data-loss is irrelevant. $f(x) = x \operatorname{mod} 11$ is an example with a lot of "data-loss" which is not one-way. To qualify as a OWF, there must be no way to efficiently find ***any*** input which results in a given output.

Comment: @FutureSecurity I know, a perfect one-way hash function would be exactly that, because there wouldn't exist a better method than brute-force. I didn't say that data-loss is a property of one-way functions, I only explained a little bit further how hashes work in general.

Comment: @user2505282 your notation is backwards from the standard notation. It is not $f(N)=(p,q)$ that is hard, that's the *inverse* of the one way function, under the semiprime factoring difficulty assumption.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend reading Barak's recent survey titled "[The Complexity of Public-Key Cryptography](https://eprint.iacr.org/2017/365)". The survey explores the assumptions required for one-way functions and public-key cryptography (loosely speaking, the latter requires more structured assumptions compared to the former). There (in §2) you can find several candidate constructions of one-way functions from diverse problems arising from cryptography (e.g., stream ciphers, hash functions), complexity theory (e.g., the planted SAT and [planted Clique problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planted_clique)), combinatorics (e.g., [Goldreich's one-way function](http://people.csail.mit.edu/rmiller/ram9a-dmp-thesis.pdf)) and learning theory, and he argues why these are plausibly one-way.